# Why wp_is_post_autosave doesn't return anything?

Tags: autosave

After saving a post I check the console and $is_autosave is simply not set

```
function save_func($post_id){
  $is_autosave = wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id );
  file_put_contents('php://stderr', print_r("Autosave: ".$is_autosave, TRUE));
}
add_action('save_post','save_func');
```

**Output:**

Autosave:

Technically since it's not an autosave the result should be:

**Output:**

Autosave: 0

Comment: [Return Values: (boolean/integer) Boolean false if not a revision, ID of autosave's parent otherwise](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_post_autosave). Zero is not equal to boolean false.